# circulation implications of removing a hallway header

Tags: heating, central-heating

Sorry for the grainy pics but should be sufficient.

The header above the entry to the hallway from the living room is non-bearing and I'd like to remove it.  Question about its usefulness tho, and I'm thinking out loud:

We are from Texas and this house is in Tennessee where it gets colder a bit.  The thermostat is in the hallway at 60" (chest height) and I notice that the bedrooms and hallway are about ~8-10 degrees F warmer than the living, dining and kitchen.  Return air is in the hall below the thermostat.

Just to be thorough, I'm wondering if the header is intended as a design feature for airflow regulation and also what it might do in the summer (which I haven't been here for yet).  My gut instinct is remove it but I thought it was worth asking.  Thank you.

[image]
[image]

Comment: If non load bearing, then probably put there in case someone wanted a door, just slap a door frame in, and it looks nicer to some.

Comment: hm.. I've never seen that style for a hallway entry.  As long as it's not an airflow feature then sounds like it's going to say goodbye :)